# DAPP vs Consensus attacks

Tags: ether, dapps, consensus, bitcoin, attacks

Are contracts such as DAPPs on the Ethereum block chain vulnerable to consensus attacks like Bitcoin is, such as say, to Gambler's ruin?

Comment: What exactly do you mean when you talk about the Gambler's ruin with respect to blockchain?

Comment: @SilverCookies I meant that seeing how a double spend attack can theoretically be carried out in bitcoin similar to Gambler's ruin, can something similar be done in DAPPs and other contracts?

Comment: Or any other consensus based attack for that matter.

Answer (score 1):

It's a pretty broad question, so I'll try to address it as two topics.

**First layer**. The Ethereum protocol exists to ensure that Smart Contracts execute *as programmed*. There is a layer of technology, research and discussion devoted to ensuring that the network itself is reliable and performs its function. Any issue or development at this level would generally have possible relevance for all Smart Contracts in a similar way that any protocol-level discussion about Bitcoin has possible relevance to all wallets.

**Second layer**. Assuming Smart Contracts reliably execute *as programmed*, considerable responsibility for ensuring desired results rests with the Smart Contract developer. It's vital to ensure that the contract does what the developer thinks it does under all circumstances.

Comment: So you're saying saying these smart contracts are not subject to attacks like Gambler's ruin?